# how separate string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm try to list a sequence of numbers separated by comma and apostrophe. I have a problem. I don't know how to add apostrophe and comma. I should have '09335634088','09393396698','09172828465' but I have 09335634088,09393396698,09172828465  Can you help me? Here is my code.

```
 $('#example-console-rows').text(rows_selected.join(","));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easily done with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
$('#example-console-rows').text(rows_selected.map(x => "'" + x + "'").join(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Array#prototype#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#prototype#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const arr = [
 09335634088,
 09393396698,
 09172828465
];

const res = arr.map(x => `'${x}'`).join(',');
console.log(res);
```

So your code would look like:

```
$('#example-console-rows').text(rows_selected.map(x => `'${x}'`).join(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
 '09335634088',
 '09393396698',
 '09172828465'
];

console.log(`'${arr.join("','")}'`);
```